# getting remote exception while calling an ejb3 method

Tags: ejb-3.0

```
method(){
try{
some code..
}
catch(Exception e)
{
throw new userDefineException();
}
}
```

//    while calling the above method from the java client I am gettine remote exception but i      am expecting to get UserdefineException.

Answer (score 2):

EJB container will wrap undeclared (system) exceptions in RemoteException (or EJBException for local views).  To avoid this, you should either:

1. Change UserDefineException to extend Exception rather than RuntimeException, and add UserDefineException to the throws clause of the remote interface.
2. Annotation UserDefineException with `@ApplicationException`, or specify it as `<application-exception>com.example.UserDefineException</application-exception>` in ejb-jar.xml.